# Static member function cannot access protected member of class

Tags: c++, function, static, protected

My understanding is static member functions can access private, protected members of the class.
Here in my code, sortPoint2DXAsc should be able to access X and Y since it's member function of Point2D. But I get this error:

```
Point2D.h: In function ‘bool sortPoint2DXAsc(const Point2D&, const Point2D&)’:
Point2D.h:22:7: error: ‘int Point2D::x’ is protected
Point2D.cpp:41:21: error: within this context
Point2D.h:22:7: error: ‘int Point2D::x’ is protected
Point2D.cpp:41:31: error: within this context
Point2D.h:22:7: error: ‘int Point2D::x’ is protected
Point2D.cpp:41:44: error: within this context
Point2D.h:22:7: error: ‘int Point2D::x’ is protected
Point2D.cpp:41:55: error: within this context
Point2D.h:23:7: error: ‘int Point2D::y’ is protected
Point2D.cpp:41:67: error: within this context
Point2D.h:23:7: error: ‘int Point2D::y’ is protected
Point2D.cpp:41:77: error: within this context
```

---

Here is my code:

```
class Point2D
{

    protected:  
        int x;
        int y;

    public:
        //Constructor
        Point2D();
        Point2D (int x, int y);

        //Accessors
        int getX();
        int getY();

        //Mutators
        void setX (int x);
        void setY (int y);

        static bool sortPoint2DXAsc (const Point2D& left, const Point2D& right);

};

bool sortPoint2DXAsc (const Point2D& left, const Point2D& right) 
{
    return (left.x < right.x) || ((left.x == right.x) && (left.y < right.y));
}
```

Comment: The function is not part of the class. Change to `bool Point2D::sortPoint2DXAsc...`

Comment: wow thanks for pointing it out. Don't know how i missed that.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want something like [this code tested](http://ideone.com/6ZkmEK) :

```
class Point2D {

protected:  
    int x;
    int y;

public:
    //Constructor
    Point2D();
    Point2D (int x, int y);

    //Accessors
    int getX() const {return x; }
    int getY() const {return y;}

    //Mutators
    void setX (int x) {/*Do something with x*/}
    void setY (int y) {/*Do something with y*/}

    static bool sortPoint2DXAsc(const Point2D& left, const Point2D& right);

};


bool Point2D::sortPoint2DXAsc (const Point2D& left, const Point2D& right) 
{
        return (left.getX() < right.getX()) || ((left.getX() == right.getX()) && (left.getY() < right.getY()));
}
```

You can use static since you're not using `this` in your function. For example, if you was using `this->x` instead of `left.getX()`, you would have received an error because your function is static.

Now, here's a [second example](http://ideone.com/8Ec3W0) where you can access `x` and `y` without accessors.
Since you're inside your class definition, `x` and `y` are accessible from `left` and `right` which are instance of `Point2D` even if they are protected.